# Liferay - change locale by page

Tags: liferay, velocity

I have a problem with changing the language in my portal. I use liferay 6.0.5, the default language is French in my portal, and there are some pages translated to English. I set the pages in portal_normal.vm as follows:

```
# set ($ pages_EN = ["/ services", "/ equipment"])
# if ($ language_id == 'en_GB')
#   foreach ($ mypage pages_EN in $)
#     if ($ == $ mypage layout.getFriendlyURL ())
#       set ($ = $ rtlCssURL themeDisplay.getTheme (). getContextPath () + $themeDisplay.getTheme (). getCssPath () + "/ custom_en.css")
#       css ($ rtlCssURL)
#     end
#   end
# end
```

I joined the portlet tongue on my portal_normal.vm to change language it works well.

**What I want to do:** When am in a EN page and I click on a page which has not translated to EN, I want to change the language (en -> fr) then redirect to the clicked link . Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As there's no such thing as a "translated page" in Liferay, this is actually hard to answer in a way that will make sense: You might have translated "every article" on a page to a different language, but what will be the behaviour when you have 2 out of 3 articles translated?

The functionality I can imagine will be possible out-of-the-box in Liferay: Given the URLs http://example.com/home, http://example.com/fr/home and http://example.com/en/home, the last ones (with the language code) will show the requested language if that's available. The first URL will show the language that is available and best matches the user's requirement: Either through having stated that one is there preferred language (by being logged in and having set the default language in their profile) or by browser-content-negotiation (you can configure your preferred languages in your browser. This will be carried forward to the webserver)

Another option, that I doubt you speak about here, is that you're speaking about translated page titles, but they will also be covered by the behaviour I mentioned above.

If your scenario is different from that, please rephrase the question. As far as I can imagine what you ask for, I can't think of any requirement for redirects. The language will be chosen automatically based on availability and preferences.